# Exception 7 [Bad data address] occurred and ignored

Tags: assembly, mips, gnu-assembler

I'm very new to mips and I'm trying to write a program that uses subroutines to sort and output an array. I'm in the debugging process (which I'm not very good at because I don't know how to decipher the error codes) and I am getting the error:

```
Exception 7 [Bad data address] occurred and ignored
```

I think the error is occurring while I'm trying to input the values into the array. Here is that section of the code:

```
main:    
addi $sp, $sp, -104        # Save address on stack
sw $ra, 0($sp)

la $a0, S1                 # Prompt user
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5                  # Read in n
syscall
move $s1, $v0              # $s1 = n

li $s2, 0                  # $s2 = 0

inLoop:
beq $s2, $s1, loop         # for (i = 0 ; i < n)
sll $t7, $s2, 2            # i = 4i
add $t8, $s0, $t7          # $t8 = address of a[i]

li $v0, 5                  # Read in n
syscall
move $t8, $v0              # a[i] = n

addi $s2, $s2, 1           # i++
j inLoop
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The error message is known - its *"Exception 7 [Bad data address] occurred and ignored"*.

Comment: `move $t8, $v0              # a[i] = n` <-- that comment doesn't match the instruction. You're not writing anything to memory - you're just copying the value of one register into another.